# How to combine list and individual elements into one tuple in python?

Tags: python

I have a few variables in python3:

```
a = 1
b = [2,3,4]
c = 5
```

I want to get a tuple which is from above variables, like: `(1,2,3,4,5)`

what is the easiest way to do that in python3?

Comment: If you're using Python 3, you can use the `*` unpacking operator: `x = (a, *b, c)`

Comment: that's cool, thanks.

Comment: See https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/201244/flatten-an-array-in-python for a generic flattening function that can take lists and ints alike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a tuple in Python is as simple as putting the stuff you need in a tuple in parentheses:

```
my_tuple = (1, 2, 3)
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
another_tuple = (a, b, c)  # also works with variables, or anything else with a value
```

And if what you want in the tuple is in something else that can be unpacked, like a list or a tuple itself, you can use the unpacking operator `*` to unpack it into the new tuple:

```
a = 1
b = [2,3,4]
c = 5
my_tuple = (a, *b, c)
```

Not your question, but note that you can also get stuff from a tuple without using the `*` operator, as it's implied in an assignment statement:

```
x, _, z = my_tuple  # continued from before
```

In this example, what was in `a` (`1`) is now also in `x` and what was in `c` also in `z`. What was in `b` and in the second position of the tuple gets discards (that's what the underscore `_` here means, "don't care".)

You use the unpack operator in cases where you explicitly need to unpack and you're constructing some new variable, or need the elements of the tuple separately where they could also be used as a tuple. For example, when calling a function:

```
a_tuple = ('Hi there', 'John')


def greeting(phrase='Hello', name='world'):
    print(f'{phrase}, {name}!')


greeting(*a_tuple)
```

In this example, calling `greeting` as `greeting(a_tuple)` would give you the very nasty result of `('Hi there', 'John'), world!`, clearly not what you want, but you can still use the tuple with the unpack operator.

And the other obvious example is one like the one solving OP's question.

Comment: `x, _, z = *my_tuple` gives me `SyntaxError: can't use starred expression here`

Comment: Apologies, you don't even need the unpack operator there - updating. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a new tuple as shown below.

```
newTuple=(a, *b, c)
```

**Note:** *b unpacks list **b** into variables and add each variable to indexes of **newTuple**

Comment: Using `[]` doesn't create a `tuple`, it creates a `list`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the most pythonic solution:

```
a = 1
b = [2,3,4]
c = 5
res = a,*b,c
# output: (1,2,3,4,5)
```

**Note**: To create the new tuple, round brackets are not necessary in Python3

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways is shown below

```
from functools import reduce
import operator

# create a bunch of lists, reduce them to one list and finally convert to tuple
result = tuple(reduce(operator.add, ([a], b, [c])))
print(result)
```